# Pass an array from BASH to PHP

Tags: php, bash, shell

I am listing all files on my desktop using a shell script. Below is my shell script:

```
 #! /bin/bash

myFiles=`dir /home/chb-pc/Desktop`
#echo $myFiles;

count=0
for f in $myFiles
do 
    #echo $f 
    read myArray[$count] = f
    `expr $count + 1`
done

echo myArray
```

The above script will list file names of all files.
I need to store the output in a variable and send it to PHP where i will loop each and every files in that variable and do some stuff.

Below is my PHP script:

```
<?php

$output = shell_exec("sh /home/chb-pc/Desktop/files.sh");

foreach ($output as $files) {
    echo $files . "<br>";
}
?>
```

I know my shell script does not seem right, but i tried various syntax and can't find the right one.

Comment: your bash script doesn't work at all, at least on Debian, as `read` is the command to read from `stdin`, why won't you just use `glob()` in PHP?

Comment: I didn't know about this function. Thanks for the suggestion. This makes life easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just avoid using both, PHP is quite capable of listing a directory:

```php
<?php
$dir = '/home/chb-pc/Desktop';
foreach (new DirectoryIterator($dir) as $fileInfo) {
    if($fileInfo->isDot()) continue;
    echo $fileInfo->getFilename() . "\n";
}
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: as several others have pointed out, it's possible (and generally better) to get the list of filenames directly in php, without involving a shell script at all. But if you do need to use a shell script for some reason...

Since unix filenames can contain any character except for "/" and ASCII NUL (character #0) (and file paths can contain "/"), the standardish way to pass lists of filenames is with NUL delimiters. Getting a list of filenames from a command like `ls` that doesn't use a clean format like this is hard, so it's best to get the list by just using a raw wildcard (e.g. `*`) and letting bash itself get the list. The one slightly tricky thing in this part is that by default, if there are no matching files, the shell will just leave "*" there rather than producing an empty list, so you want bash's `nullglob` option enabled, and that's a bash-only feature (so run this with `bash`, not just `sh`!).

```
#! /bin/bash

cd /home/chb-pc/Desktop || exit

shopt -s nullglob    # If there are no files, don't just print the "*"!
printf '%s\0' *      # Print each filename followed by a NUL
```

There's another slightly tricky thing about capturing this in php: the list has a NUL after each filename, including the last one, but `explode` assumes the delimiters are *between* items. As a result, it'll wind up with an empty item at the end of the array, and you need to remove that with `array_pop`.

```
<?php
$output = explode("\x00", shell_exec('bash /home/chb-pc/Desktop/files.sh'));
array_pop($output);

foreach ($output as $files) {
        echo $files . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: The check for the directory here `/home/chb-pc/Desktop || exit` does not work, you can't execute a directory. `[[ -d /home/chb-pc/Desktop ]] || exit` would work, but better yet would be to enable `set -e` (preferably `set -euo pipefail`) and just cd in to the directory `cd /home/chb-pc/Desktop` which due to `set -e` would exit the script if the directory didn't exist.

Comment: @lyte D'oh, that was a copy-paste error; it was supposed to be a `cd` command (and `exit` the script if `cd` fails for any reason). Fixed now.

Comment: Fair enough, that makes more sense now

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `glob`

```php
$fileList = glob('temp/*');
```

and now you can iterate and perform your set of actions.

Answer (score -1):

I think that an ideal solution would be if your shell script output a comma-separated list, and your PHP code would look like so:

```
<?php

$output = explode(',', shell_exec('sh /home/chb-pc/Desktop/files.sh');

foreach ($output as $files) {
    echo $files . "<br>";
}
?>
```

May that work for you?

Comment: probably as it's filename that are listed, much better using "\n" as separator... otherwise you'll have to escape commas from filenames. And bash script could probably be remplace by a simple "find /my/dir"

Comment: using `\n` as a separator would also mean you have to do escaping for files containing the newline character, better would be `\0`, as files are not allowed to contain that character